# How to verify whether a given winobject text is selected or not using qtp

Tags: qtp

I tried using:

```
Window("x").Winobject("y").GetRoProperty("selText")
```

But there was no output, although it [says here](http://www.articlesontesting.com/2010/10/getroproperty-in-qtp-continued.html) that `SelText` is a valid property.

Comment: I've never heard of a `selText` property, did you see a reference to it somewhere or did you just make it up and hope it will work?

Comment: http://www.articlesontesting.com/2010/10/getroproperty-in-qtp-continued.html
I read it on this link
But it is not working

Comment: Have you tried sending the command to copy the current selection to the clipboard and then reading the clipboard?

Answer (score 0):

The site you link to describes the `VbEditor` test object, however you're using a `WinObject` which has a different list of supported properties.

In general each test object supports a different list of properties (although some are common to many objects) and you should consult the documentation to see which properties are supported.

As far as I know there's no way to get the selected text of a `WinObject` control. If you application is supported by UFT's **VB Addin** you should try enabling it in the *addin manager* when UFT is launched, otherwise I don't know of a way to do this in UFT.

Comment: Make sure that your AUT is added to the Record and Run settings. If it's still identified as a `WinObject` then it's probably not a **VB** application and you can't use `SelText`

Answer (score 0):

Did you give a try with file/image compare for before and after selection?

```
WpfWindow("HP MyFlight Sample Application").WpfEdit("byNumberWatermark").CaptureBitmap "C:\Before.png",True
WpfWindow("HP MyFlight Sample Application").WpfRadioButton("byNumberRadio").Set
WpfWindow("HP MyFlight Sample Application").WpfEdit("byNumberWatermark").CaptureBitmap "C:\After.png",True
Set imageCompare = CreateObject("Mercury.FileCompare")
returnValue = imageCompare.IsEqualBin("C:\Before.png","C:\After.png",1,1)
If returnValue = 1 Then
    Msgbox "Both images are Same"
Else
    Msgbox "Both images are not same"
End If
```

isEqualBin Parameter 3 and 4 explains Const FC_DIFF_SIZE = 1

In your case, it would be selection of winobject before and after.